# IEEE two column format

Tags: two-column, ieee-style

This should be a quick answer that I can't seem to find again.  A while ago, I found out that I can use a one line addition in the preamble to format the document to the IEEE standard. It wasn't a reference to a style sheet or something else, but was integrated into TexLive. What is it again?

Comment: `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`?

Comment: @Werner, when I use that, I get a compilation error saying that 'IEEEtran.cls' is not found

Comment: [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) forms part of both MiKTeX and TeX Live. If you don't have it, install it by following the direction in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  In the mean time, I pulled the IEEEtran.cls file from the IEEE website

Answer (score 2):

[`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) forms part of both MiKTeX and TeX Live, and should therefore be included in your distribution by default. As such, using

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
```

should suffice to format your document according to IEEE's standard.

For manual installation, files are also available for download on the [`IEEEtran` homepage](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/).